# Web API - Self close tag instead of i:nil

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, datacontractserializer

I am using Web API with `DataContract` serialization.
The output looks like this:

```
<Data>
<Status>
  <Date>2014-08-13T00:30:00</Date>
  <ID>312</ID>
  <Option>No Limitation</Option>
  <Value i:nil="true" />
</Status>
<Status>
  <Date>2014-08-13T01:00:00</Date>
  <ID>312</ID>
  <Option>No Limitation</Option>
  <Value i:nil="true" />
</Status>
<Status>
  <Date>2014-08-13T01:30:00</Date>
  <ID>312</ID>
  <Option>No Limitation</Option>
  <Value i:nil="true" />
</Status>
<Status>
  <Date>2014-08-13T02:00:00</Date>
  <ID>312</ID>
  <Option>No Limitation</Option>
  <Value i:nil="true" />
</Status>
```

I was able to remove all the extra namespaces by doing:

```
[DataContract(Namespace="")]
public class Status
```

But the only attribute left is the `i:nil` attribute.
What should i do in order to remove the i:nil attribute?

Comment: Would this solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12465285/conditional-datacontract-serialization-in-webapi, `DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]`

Comment: @Prescott, that will remove the empty element at all. What I want is to show the element without the `i:nil` attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is to make the code "think" that instead of having a null value, it actually has an empty string. You can do that by being a little smart with the property getter (see below). Just remember to add a comment explaining why you're doing that so other people who will maintain the code know what's going on.

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class Status
{
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Option { get; set; }

    private string value;

    [DataMember]
    public string Value
    {
        get { return this.value ?? ""; }
        set { this.value = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Simple and nice. That was exactly what I needed, Thanks.

Comment: Great, works for me. After this change I had to change the code that uses this value from `Value != null` to `string.IsNullOrEmpty(Value)`

Answer (score 6):

You need to set the [`EmitDefaultValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.emitdefaultvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) property in the `DataMember` attribute

```
[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
```

Be sure not to set this attribute on members that have the `IsRequired = true` set to them.

**Edit**

You may also iterate the XML manually and remove the `nil` attributes using [`LINQ 2 XML`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx):

```
XNamespace i = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"XmlHere"); // This may be replaced with XElement.Parse if the XML is in-memory

        xdoc.Descendants()
                 .Where(node => (string)node.Attribute(i + "nil") == "true")
                 .Remove();
```

Comment: That will remove the empty element at all, isn't it? I want to show the element but without the `i:nil` attribute.

Comment: It will remove any null element, yes. I edited my answer with a way to manually remove the specified attributes.

Comment: What you are proposing is right, but in the case of Web API, you can't manipulate the XML like this, it is an internal serialization.

Comment: You can by implementing `IXmlSerializable` yourself.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#xml_pertype)

Comment: That will force me to use `XmlSerializer` but I need to use `DataContract`. Is there a way to remove `i:nil` attribute using `DataContract`?

Comment: I haven't ever done that with `DataContractSerializer`. Sorry.