# No data displayed only brackets in web API C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm quite new to Web API in C#.

This is my JSON response:

```
{
    "<chart_type>": [
        { "name": "entity" },
        { "display_name": "entity display name" },
        {
            "kpi": [
                {
                    "name":"<kpi>",
                    "display_name":"test",
                    "required": [
                        { "test": "test" },
                        { "test1": "test" }
                        ],
                    "optional": [        
                        { "test": "test" },
                        { "test": "test" }
                        ],
                    "objects": {
                        "<Fieldname>": 
                        {
                            "display_name":"<entity display name>",
                            "type": "<select or text>",
                            "default": "default value (already selected)",
                            "list": {
                                "<id>": "<value>"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

but after I used postman this is the display:

[image: API output]

and this is my DefinitionDTO

```
public partial class Test
{
    [JsonProperty("<chart_type>", Required = Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public ChartType[] chart_type { get; set; }
}

public partial class ChartType
{
    [JsonProperty("name", Required = Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string entity_name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("display_name", Required = Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string entity_display_name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("kpi", Required = Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public Kpi[] Kpi { get; set; }
}

public partial class Kpi
{
    [JsonProperty("name", Required = Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string kpi_name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("display_name", Required = Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string kpi_display_name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("required", Required = Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public RequiredElement[] kpi_required { get; set; }

    //[JsonProperty("optional", Required = Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    //public Optional[] kpi_optional { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("objects", Required = Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public Objects Objects { get; set; }
}

public partial class RequiredElement
{
    [JsonProperty("test", Required = Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Test { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("test1", Required = Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Test1 { get; set; }
}

public partial class Objects
{
    [JsonProperty("<Fieldname>", Required = Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public Fieldname Fieldname { get; set; }
}

public partial class Fieldname
{
    [JsonProperty("display_name", Required = Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type", Required = Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("default", Required = Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Default { get; set; }

    //[JsonProperty("list", Required = Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    //public List List { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]` to your DTO's.

You have overriden default ASP.NET JSON serializer, If you're using the ASP.NET Web API, then you should be aware that the default JSON serializer isn't the `DataContractJsonSerializer` (DCJS), but JSON.NET instead. So unless you explicitly configure your `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` to use DCJS, you need another attribute to get the same behavior (`JsonProperty`, and its `DefaultValueHandling` property).

```
[DataContract]
public partial class Fieldname
{
[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
[JsonProperty("display_name", Required = Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public string DisplayName { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("type", Required = Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public string Type { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("default", Required = Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public string Default { get; set; }

//[JsonProperty("list", Required = Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
//public List List { get; set; }
}
```

For More to know please follow this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12465285/conditional-datacontract-serialization-in-webapi)

Comment: Hi sir, I try to change it into         public class ChartType
        {
            public string kpi_name { get; set; }
            public string kpi_display_name { get; set; }
            public List<Kpi> kpi { get; set; }
        }

        public class RootObject
        {
            public List<ChartType> chart_type { get; set; }
        }


when I call the RootObject it doesn't display the data first data, but when I try to call 
public class ChartType
it will display the first two values and third one is null.

I can't call the third one which is one of my problem.

Comment: [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage definition()
        {

            var result = _definitionRepository.definition();
            if (result == null)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, " Bad request");
            }
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);

        }

Comment: if possible, Need repository code also.. and add `DataMember` into all properties.

Comment: public class DefinitionRepository : IDefinitionRepository
    {
        private HistogramEntities _db = new HistogramEntities();
        public List<ChartType> definition()
        {
            var results = _db.Database.SqlQuery<ChartType>("get_definition_list").ToList();
            return results;
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<Root> definition()
        {
            var all = _db
                .kpi_definition
                .Include("KPI")
                .Select(dl => new Root
                {
                    //chart_type = dl.chart_type,
                    chart_type = new List<Chart>
                    {
                       new Chart { entity_name = dl.entity_name ,
                                   entity_display_name = dl.entity_display_name,
                                   kpi = new List<KPI>
                                   {
                                      new KPI {
                                               kpi_name = dl.kpi_name,
                                               kpi_display_name = dl.kpi_display_name,
                                               required = new List<Required>
                                               {
                                                   new Required
                                                   {
                                                       //kpi_required = dl.kpi_required
                                                   }
                                               },
                                               optional = new List<Optional>
                                               {
                                                   new Optional
                                                   {
                                                       //kpi_optional = dl.kpi_optional
                                                   }
                                               },
                                               objects = new List<Objects>
                                               {
                                                   new Objects
                                                   {
                                                       field_name = new List<FieldName>
                                                       {
                                                           new FieldName
                                                           {
                                                            entity_display_name = dl.entity_display_name,
                                                            type = "Select or Text",
                                                            @default = "default value(already selected)",
                                                            list = "",
                                                            ID = dl.ID
                                                           }
                                                       }

                                                   }
                                               }
                                              }
                                   }
                                 }
                    }
                }).ToList();
            return all;
        }
```