# public ChartType[] chart_type { get; set; } is not passing any value?

Tags: c#, webapi

Hi follow up question regarding to
[No data displayed only brackets in web API C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59606976/no-data-displayed-only-brackets-in-web-api-c-sharp)

When I declare

```
public ChartType[] chart_type { get; set; }
```

it doesn't display any data

but when I used

```
public string chart_type { get; set; }
```

it will display all 5 rows.

because I can't continue to another object

```
public partial class ChartType
{
    [JsonProperty("name", Required = Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string entity_name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("display_name", Required = Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string entity_display_name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("kpi", Required = Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public Kpi[] Kpi { get; set; }
}
```

and so on.....

I'm currently using complex JSON structure for my web API, hope someone helps.

Comment: What if you try and manually convert a sample instance of `CharType` to JSON yourself? If it fails, then you know that you have an issue with the serialization of it, and you might need to come up with your own custom serializer for it.

Comment: Noted, any links for the most accurate manual convert serialization ?

Comment: You can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29841503/json-serialization-deserialization-in-asp-net-core). The aim is for you to try and do manually what the API does automatically. This will make it easier to tackle any issues which arise.